Ubuntu 22.04 is unable to ping default gateway
See attached screenshots:

Netplan shows no error.


IP route looks good.


ifconfig shows the right IP.



Note: Ubuntu is running on top of VMware Fusion.

Please don't put photos and screenshots of the terminal. Copy the text from the terminal and paste it directly in your question then format it as code using the {_} icon above the edit window. Does your default gateway set up to respond to ping?

No, i cannot ping the default gateway

CLI printout  ===> root@eve-ng：~#_
oot@eve-ng:*# ip route detault via 192.168.1.1 dev ensss proto static 192.168.1.0/24 dew ens33 proto kernel scope link sro 192.168.1.163

Note: The ubuntu is running on top of VMWare Fusion

Please edit your question and add all these information. The comments are mainly for ask for clarification. You should always update your question.
